# Print only previous line after using GREP command

Tags: linux, grep

I want to search for a particular string in a certain file. Once found I only want to print the previous line of the greped line but not the line obtained using grep command.

cmd : `grep -B 1 line5`

```
Ex:
lin1 with some text
lin2
lin3
lin4
lin5 with some text
```

Output will be

```
lin4
lin5 with some text
```

But is there any solution where I can obtain only lin4 but not lin5.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Could use `sed` together to filter the unwanted lines.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
grep -B 1 line5 | head -1
```

to get the first line of your output

Comment: This will fail when the same word appears twice in different lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Display N lines after match
   -A is the option which prints the specified N lines after the match as shown below.
   Syntax:

   ```
   grep -A <N> "string" FILENAME
   ```
2. Display N lines before match
   -B is the option, which prints the specified N lines before the match.
   Syntax:

   ```
   grep -B <N> "string” FILENAME
   ```
3. Display N lines around match
   -C is the option, which prints the specified N lines before the match. In some occasion you might want the match to be appeared with the lines from both the side. This options shows N lines in both the side(before & after) of match.

   ```
   $ grep -C 2 "Example"  FILENAME
   ```